Controlling brushless dc pump when only 2 cables are provided
Water pump in question is the "High Flow 3M- 15M 12v Water Pump 12 Volt DC Mini Water Pump", the submersible model, from alibaba. link: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-Flow-3M-15M-12v-Water_60354764507.html?spm=a2700.shop_index.111720.3.3a4c1cc8ite8LG
now my question is how do i control the speed of this using an ESC when it only has 2 wires?

What does the data sheet say?

The short answer is that you can't use an ESC on a two wire motor. If the motor is brushless it has its own electronic controller embedded in the package. An ESC fabricates a three phase supply to a suitable controllable motor and it needs three wires to do that. You can't just connect two of the wires. See this discussion on an RC website. here
You will need to find an alternate solution. If you want to control the flow of water you can throttle the output (increases head at pump, decreases flow) or  use a bypass on the output that returns water to the source (increase flow at pump, decreases head).see here
I do not know if simply reducing the input voltage will work on this particular pump. It is sometimes an option.
This Indian website has a similar model pump (ad20p-1230e) and says speed can be controlled using PWM. here but other websites listing this pump do not mention this.
This similar pump does offer PWM speed control here at alibaba
